# Package permissions of a single user in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem, acl, aem-6

I have a user named readuser, I created from useradmin and I gave few read permissions on content for that user. Why I try to get the package of the user through ACLs, I'm getting the permissions of all users existing in my local.What it doing is basically packaging all the permissions under content of all users.
But I want permissions of only my readuser.

How do I get the permissions of readuser alone.

Thanks
Sharath

Comment: You should add the code with what you tried so far

Comment: I created users from useradmin.

Comment: What  are you using to create the ACL package? this: https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/packagers/acl-packager/index.html? or something else?